# how to add / remove color from image using action script

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, adobe, flash-builder

I am facing an issue to add / remove colors from an image. 
For example I have  abc.png image containing 3 colors (red, green, blue). I want to remove the color area against red from the image without affecting the other image colors.

Please share with me, If anyone having idea about it.

Thanks.

Comment: something similar , take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272155/iterating-each-pixel-of-a-bitmap-image-in-actionscript

Answer (score 0):

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData( s.width, s.height, true, 0 );
bitmapData.draw( s );

for ( var i:int = 0 ; i < bitmapData.width ; i++ ) {
    for ( var j:int = 0 ; j < bitmapData.height ; j++ ) {
        var pixelColor:uint = bitmapData.getPixel( i, j );

        var redChannel:uint = ( ( pixelColor >> 16 ) & 0xFF );
        var greenChannel:uint = ( ( pixelColor >> 8 ) & 0xFF );
        var blueChannel:uint = ( pixelColor & 0xFF );

        //if ( // COMPARE COLOR TO YOURS USING EITHER YUV or CIE color space // ) {
            bitmapData.setPixel( i, j, 0 );
        }
    }
}
```

Compare colors using either color space you want to, this are just examples. ( You cannot
compare color similarity using RGB cs ).

Also remember that using draw() on exact children will lose all of its transform, you can consider using parent or any other solution.